# Change date format in first column using awk/sed

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a shell script which is automatically ran each morning which appends that days results to a text file. The file should have todays date on the first column followed by results separated by commas. I use the command date +%x to get the day in the required format (dd/mm/yy). However on one computer date +%x returns mm/dd/yyyy ( any idea why this is the case?). I then sort the data in the file in date order.

Here is a snippet of such a text file

```
29/11/12,9654.80,194.32,2.01,7.19,-7.89,7.65,7.57,3.98,9625.27,160.10,1.66,4.90,-4.79,6.83,4.84,3.54                
03/12/12,5184.22,104.63,2.02,6.88,-6.49,7.87,6.67,4.10,5169.52,93.81,1.81,5.29,-5.45,7.87,5.37,4.10                
04/12/12,5183.65,103.18,1.99,6.49,-6.80,8.40,6.66,4.38,5166.04,95.44,1.85,6.04,-6.49,8.40,6.28,4.38                
11/07/2012,5183.65,102.15,1.97,6.78,-6.36,8.92,6.56,4.67,5169.48,96.67,1.87,5.56,-6.10,8.92,5.85,4.67                
07/11/2012,5179.39,115.57,2.23,7.64,-6.61,8.83,7.09,4.62,5150.17,103.52,2.01,7.01,-6.08,8.16,6.51,4.26                
11/26/2012,5182.66,103.30,1.99,7.07,-5.76,7.38,6.37,3.83,5162.81,95.47,1.85,6.34,-5.40,6.65,5.84,3.44                
11/30/2012,5180.82,95.19,1.84,6.51,-5.40,7.91,5.92,4.12,5163.98,91.82,1.78,5.58,-5.07,7.05,5.31,3.65
```

Is it possible to change the date format for the latter four lines to the correct date format using awk or sed? I only wish to change the date format for those in the form mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using two different flavors (versions) of `date`. To check which versions you've got, I think `GNU date` accepts the `--version` flag whereas other versions, like `BSD/OSX` will not accept this flag.

Since you may be using completely different systems, it's probably safest to avoid `date` completely and use `perl` to print the current date:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime("%d/%m/%y", localtime) . "\n"'
```

If you are sure you have `GNU awk` on both machines, you could use it like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print strftime("%d/%m/%y") }'
```

---

To fix the file you've got, here's my take using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '{ print gensub(/^(..\/)(..\/)..(..,)/, "\\2\\1\\3", "g"); next }1' file
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\(..\/\)\(..\/\)..\(..,\)/\2\1\3/' file
```

Results:

```
29/11/12,9654.80,194.32,2.01,7.19,-7.89,7.65,7.57,3.98,9625.27,160.10,1.66,4.90,-4.79,6.83,4.84,3.54                
03/12/12,5184.22,104.63,2.02,6.88,-6.49,7.87,6.67,4.10,5169.52,93.81,1.81,5.29,-5.45,7.87,5.37,4.10                
04/12/12,5183.65,103.18,1.99,6.49,-6.80,8.40,6.66,4.38,5166.04,95.44,1.85,6.04,-6.49,8.40,6.28,4.38                
07/11/12,5183.65,102.15,1.97,6.78,-6.36,8.92,6.56,4.67,5169.48,96.67,1.87,5.56,-6.10,8.92,5.85,4.67                
11/07/12,5179.39,115.57,2.23,7.64,-6.61,8.83,7.09,4.62,5150.17,103.52,2.01,7.01,-6.08,8.16,6.51,4.26                
26/11/12,5182.66,103.30,1.99,7.07,-5.76,7.38,6.37,3.83,5162.81,95.47,1.85,6.34,-5.40,6.65,5.84,3.44                
30/11/12,5180.82,95.19,1.84,6.51,-5.40,7.91,5.92,4.12,5163.98,91.82,1.78,5.58,-5.07,7.05,5.31,3.65
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work: `sed -re 's/^([0-9][0-9])\/([0-9][0-9])\/[0-9][0-9]([0-9][0-9])(.*)$/\2\/\1\/\3\4/'`

It can be made smaller but I made it so it would be more obvious what it does (4 groups, just switching month/day and removing first two chars of the year).

Tip: If you don't want to `cat` the file you could to the changes `in place` with `sed -i`. But be careful if you put a faulty expression in you might end up breaking your source file.

**NOTE**: This assumes that IF the year is specified with 4 digits, the month/day is reversed.

Comment: How do I run this on my file and either replace that file or direct to a new file

Comment: @moadeep: You could `cat file | sed ... > outfile` or you should be able to do `sed -ire ... FILE` for in-place editing.

Comment: Small note: The last `(.*)` in regex and last `\4` isn't needed, but doesn't exactly hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

This below command will do it.

*Note:No matter how many number of lines are present in the file.this will just change the last 4 lines.*

```
tail -r your_file| awk -F, 'NR<5{split($1,a,"/");$1=a[2]"/"a[1]"/"a[3];print}1'|tail -r
```

Well i could figure out some way without using pipes and using a single awk statement and this solution does need a tail command:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{cmd="wc -l your_file";while (cmd|getline tmp);split(tmp,x)}x[1]-NR<=4{split($1,a,"/");$1=a[2]"/"a[1]"/"a[3];print}1' your_file
```

Comment: This looks like an unnecessarily complex solution. I mean two forks of tail and you still have to specify number of lines to read? Secondly the `-r` option isn't available in my `tail coreutils v8.20`

Comment: I couldn't use the -r option. Also I only want to change the date format of those in the form mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yy. This command doesn't change the yyyy to yy and switches dd and mm for all dates

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
awk -F/ 'NR<4;NR>3{a=$1;$1=$2;$2=a; print $1"/"$2"/" substr($3,3,2) substr($3,5)}' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F/ 'NR>3{x=$1;$1=$2;$2=x}1' OFS="/" file
```

By using the / as the delimiter, all you need to do is swap the 1st and 2nd fields which is done here using a temporary variable.

Comment: this will fail if the number of lines are more than 8 lines in the input file

Comment: That wants to swap the format for every date. I only want to swap those in the mm/dd/yyyy format to dd/mm/yy